# How to delete user from channel

Tags: getstream-io

When trying to delete a user, an error message is displayed:

Error removing user from conversation: Error: StreamChat error code 4: UpdateChannel failed with error: "cannot add or remove members in a distinct channel, please create a new distinct channel with the desired members"

Below is a sample code to delete a user:

```
try {
      const response = await conversation.removeMembers(
        [user.id],
        { text: `${user.name} was removed from conversation`}
      );

      console.log('Response: ', response);

      console.log(`${user.name} was removed from conversation`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error removing user from conversation: ${e}`);
    }
```

Conversation: 
[image]

On deletion, the first request returns OK status with the conversation
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into this issue also. Had to change the way that were creating channels. The docs make this really hard to find but on [this page](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/channel_conversations/) it says `You cannot add/remove members for channels created this way.`

Meaning if you want to create a channel in which members can be added and removed you have to create it like [shown here](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/initialize_channel/) where you assign the channel a unique ID that you create (we are using a UUID). Once it's been created you can add your desired members to it... and then later add or remove them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try later and write about success)

Comment: The links are broken. Please update the answer.